# HTTP headers not being set while in setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers

I'm using jQuery 2.2.4 and I have the following code:

```
var sessionProgressInterval = sessionProgress();
function sessionProgress() {
    return window.setInterval( function() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/report/session",
    data: {_token: _token},
    beforeSend : function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", "Foooo");
    },
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "Asdasd"
    }
})
    .done(function(response) { })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log( "error Sending stats:" + errorThrown );
        clearInterval(sessionProgressInterval);
    }).always(function(){ });
  }, 10000 );
};
```

I've tried setting custom headers in both ways (together and each alone) and In the network tab they don't get sent.

If I try this code outside the setInterval method,meaning I just send an ajax, it works.

Any idea why? Everything I found regarding the topic one of the two seemed to work to people.

Comment: It works fine for me in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/rw7wf74w/. Are you sure it's this code that's sending the request?

Comment: I am yes, I've logged in the `done` method and it does show. I susspect it might be an nginx problem although it's a common problem with `_` parameters, but mine doesn't that's why I have no idea what's happening

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my code is actually inside a  setInterval, when I tried this code outside of it it worked.

Comment: Still appears to work there too: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/rw7wf74w/1/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's weird. Any idea what might cause this?